# require_once not working for class?

Tags: php

The following script is used salt and hash a password and there is another method to insert it into database.

```
<?php

require_once "./Database.php";

class Register {

    function saltHashPassword($password) {
        $hashAndSalt = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        return $hashAndSalt;
    }

    function insertNewMember($username, $password) {
        $database = new Database();
        $database->insertNewMember($username, $password);
    }
}
```

The methods are called by this file

```
<?php

require_once "./helpers/Register.php";

$regiter = new Register();
$saltAndHashedPassword = $regiter->saltHashPassword("dfgsdfg");
$regiter->insertNewMember("testuser", $saltAndHashedPassword);
?>
```

When I run the script I get the following

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(./Database.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mate8/helpers/Register.php on line 3

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './Database.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/mate8/helpers/Register.php on line 3
```

I don't understand why it is not working. I have the correct path to the file. Any idea what mistake I have made here?

Both Database.php and Register.php are in the same folder "helpers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Register.php` is in `helpers` directory as implied by this line

```
require_once "./helpers/Register.php";
```

And Database.php is not in helpers directory as implied by

```
require_once "./Database.php";
```

You need to change the path in `Register.php` to look for `Database.php` one directory above it, like

```
require_once "../Database.php";
```

Comment: Database.php is also in the helpers folder

Comment: Then its include should be `require_once "./helpers/Database.php";`

Comment: you are right. It worked. Is it because the calling script imports Register.php? Is there any other way of doing this so it won't matter who is calling the helper class?